# Use vertical tab toggle multiple times

Tags: javascript, tabs, toggle

i need a toggle-tab-section with a vertical tab-menu.
I started with the base script of w3schools: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_vertical_tabs
and customized and improved it.

Now i have the problem, that i need this toggle-section multiple times on one site. So i created a parent div around the section with an unique id.

For the script now i need to get only the elements in this parent, so i tried to call them with the parent instead of "document" but this wont work for me.

```
function toggleTabs(evt, tabID, itemID) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks, wrapper;
  wrapper = document.getElementById('item' + itemID);

  tabcontent = wrapper.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = wrapper.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  wrapper.getElementById(tabID).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

Single tabsection (working) https://jsfiddle.net/029mua5h/

Multiple tabsection (not working) https://jsfiddle.net/029mua5h/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wrapper.getElementById(tabID).style.display = "block";` does not work. This is because .getElementById is not a prototype of a single element. Since id's are meant to be unique, it does not make sense to look for an id inside an element, because we know that there can only be one element with a spesific id. therefore we have to use the proper 
`document.getElementById(tabID).style.display = "block";`

```js
function toggleTabs(evt, tabID, itemID) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks, wrapper;
  wrapper = document.getElementById('item' + itemID);

  tabcontent = wrapper.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = wrapper.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(tabID).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}

.tabwrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  
}
/* Style the tab */
.tablinks {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right:0;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 30%;
  
  flex-direction: column;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tablinks button {
  display: block;
  background-color: inherit;
  color: black;
  padding: 22px 16px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
  display: flex;
  text-align: left;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tablinks button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current "tab button" class */
.tablinks button.active {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-right: 0;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 0px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 70%;
  border-left: 0;
  display: none;
}
.tabcontent.active{
  display:block;  
}
```

```html
<div id="item100" class="tabwrapper">
    <div class="tablinks">
      <button class="tablinks active" onclick="toggleTabs(event, 'tab-item111', '100')">London</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="toggleTabs(event, 'tab-item112', '100')">Paris</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="toggleTabs(event, 'tab-item113', '100')">Tokyo</button>
    </div>

    <div id="tab-item111" class="tabcontent active">
      <h3>London</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="tab-item112" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>Paris</h3>
      <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
    </div>

    <div id="tab-item113" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>Tokyo</h3>
      <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
    </div>
 </div>
<br />
<!-- ############################################### -->
<br />
<div id="item200" class="tabwrapper">
    <div class="tablinks">
      <button class="tablinks active" onclick="toggleTabs(event, 'tab-item222', '200')">London</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="toggleTabs(event, 'tab-item223', '200')">Paris</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="toggleTabs(event, 'tab-item224', '200')">Tokyo</button>
    </div>

    <div id="tab-item222" class="tabcontent active">
      <h3>London</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="tab-item223" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>Paris</h3>
      <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
    </div>

    <div id="tab-item224" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>Tokyo</h3>
      <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
    </div>
 </div>
```